# How to maintain position and size for all window sizes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend, visual-web-developer

I want the image to be at the center of the window, and of the same size irrespective of the window size. Im not sure on how to do this, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the HTML code where you're placing this image, please?

Comment: What do you mean by “center”? Vertically? Horizontally? Both? Should it be on top of other elements or does it stay within the normal document flow? Currently your question is too broad as there are so many ways to do this.

Comment: Can't answer properly without seeing your HTML and how you are placing the image. Also mention what you have tried and how it is different from your expected html behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use JavaScript to do it

In case the piscture is 600px x 400px:

```
var w = ((window.innerWidth)-600)/2;
var h = ((window.innerHeight)-400)/2;
var img = document.getELementByTagName('IMG')[0];
img.style.marginLeft = w+'px';
img.style.marginTop = h+'px';
```

Comment: Consider adding both of your answer at one place, when you want to write two. That will give a proper idea to the person who is asking.

Answer (score -2):

You must just add the concrete size of the picture in CSS, like this:

```
      img {
             width: 600px;
             height: 400px;
      }
```

The image will be 600px x 400px in all screen resolutions.

Comment: This doesn't make it centered though. For instance, use `margin: auto`